# How to read the value of wc -l command

Tags: tcl, expect

I have a requirement where I need to read the value of `wc -l` command. Basically I am running the following command to get the value **5**:

```
bash-3.2$ wc -l sample.tcl
5 sample.tcl
```

Now using **tcl** and **expect** programming, I need to check whether the value obtained above is correct or not.

Can anyone say how to write this using tcl expect programming?

Comment: wc -l filename will give you the number of lines in the file. So need to check how many lines are there.

Comment: When you say 'verify', you meant to cross verify the number of lines shown by `wc` with the number of lines present in the file actually 5 or not ?

Comment: I would say you need to get the stdout output of wc: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl26.html and then parse the number of lines with a regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to execute a shell command, you can use `exec`.

```
% set result [exec wc -l sample.tcl]; # The variable 'result' will have the output
5 sample.tcl
% puts $result
5 sample.tcl
```

Comment: But when I am adding this piece of code within a program, then it is throwing the error message "sample.tcl- no such file or directory" even though the file is present. I tried with absolute path also. Still the same error.

Comment: You are missing something else. Share the complete code then.

Comment: Here is the code:

  set fname "Sample.tcl"
  puts "\n++++ The value of fname is $fname++++\n"
  send "cat > $fname\r"
        after 1000
        send "default ks\r"
        after 1000
        send "prompt 0\r"
        after 1000
        send "label ks\r"
        after 1000
        send " debug\r"
        after 1000
        send " error\r"
        after 1000  
  set var [exec wc -l $fname]
        puts "****The value of #line is $var*****"

Comment: In your code, the filename is `Sample.tcl`, not `sample.tcl`. Check it.

Comment: @RDX: don't put code longer than a command invocation or a statement in a comment. Add it to your question instead, where it is easier to read and more helpful to those who try to understand the question.

Comment: Ok..sorry for giving like that. Now have pasted it in that section.

Answer (score 1):

You can independently count the number of lines in a file using Tcl:

```
# I assume that the file is already opened and that the OS file pointer is at the start of the file
while {[gets $f dummyVariable] >= 0} {
    incr count
}
```

The `gets` command reads a line, so we just need to count the number of times it succeeds. (In that mode of use, it returns `-1` on EOF.)

Comment: Whether the value is _correct_ is a different thing…

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
    set fname "Sample.tcl"
    puts "\n++++ The value of fname is $fname++++\n"
    send "cat > $fname\r"
    after 1000
    send "default ks\r"
    after 1000
    send "prompt 0\r"
    after 1000
    send "label ks\r"
    after 1000
    send " debug\r"
    after 1000
    send " error\r"
    after 1000      
    set var [exec wc -l $fname]
    puts "****The value of #line is $var*****"
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in the comment section of my answer, In your code, the filename is `Sample.tcl`, not `sample.tcl`.

Comment: What is the error? We shouldn't be guessing, really.

Comment: `wc` output is easier to parse without the filename: `set var [exec wc -l < $fname]`